# Bootstrap vs posterior for linear regression

Tags: linear-model, bootstrap, posterior

I'm curious if Bootstrapped Frequentist methods are analogous to Bayesian methods with uninformative priors (I know, there's debate to whether this actually exists.)

For a simple example, suppose that Model A is Bayesian linear regression of {x,y}. And Model B is a collection models, B[i], where x[i] is the ith bootstrapped sample of x.

Both should give a distribution over the values that the intercept and slope could take on.

Is model B design done in practice and why or why not?

Comment: Your last question is not very clear. Are you asking if bootstrap for regression..?